# probability problem: train line

Tags: probability

I can't figure out the solution of the following problem:

> The main line train starts at 5.00AM and the harbor line train starts at 5.02AM. Each train has the frequency of 10 minutes.If a guy goes in the morning at a random time what is the probability of he getting main line train?

How to get the result?

Thank you

Comment: What does morning mean? I assume that random time, unreasonably, means uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1):

**One approach:**

Try drawing a "number line" to depict the start of the morning until the end.

("In the morning" left open to interpretation has an effect, since if it means "any time in the AM," then the 5 hours before the main line starts will guarantee it is where he ends up.)

Once you have illustrated the number line, say, from 5AM to 12PM, put in a red dot every time the main line arrives, and a blue dot every time the harbor line arrives.

Next, color the times between the arrivals appropriately: Use red to indicate "the guy would take the main line," and use blue to indicate "the guy would take the harbor line."

**Think carefully** about which segments should be which color!

This will allow you to find the total length of time for each, and, ultimately to solve the problem; hopefully, you will spot some sort of pattern in the process of making such a chart.

(Or, after finding the solution, you can "look back" to see what you notice!)